# Convert charts to picture powerpoint

Tags: vba, converters, powerpoint

I usually use this one couple times for converting charts to image in PPT. But this time, when running this code, it shown " Error 242, Subject Required"

Anyone master of VBA can help me fix it?

Here the code:

```
 `Sub EnumChartsInPresentation()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ctr As Long
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For ctr = sld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If GetShapeType(sld.Shapes(ctr)) = msoChart Then
            Call ConvertChartToImage(sld, sld.Shapes(ctr))
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub

Function GetShapeType(shp As Shape) As MsoShapeType
If shp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
    If shp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoChart Then
        GetShapeType = msoChart
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
GetShapeType = shp.Type
End Function

Sub ConvertChartToImage(sld As Slide, shp As Shape)
Dim shpChartImage As Object
shp.Copy
DoEvents
Set shpChartImage = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)
With shpChartImage
    .Left = shp.Left
    .Top = shp.Top

    Do While shp.ZOrderPosition < shpChartImage.ZOrderPosition
        Call shpChartImage.ZOrder(msoSendBackward)
    Loop

    shp.Visible = False
    'shp.Delete
    'Set shp = Nothing
End With
End Sub`
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Have you tried researching the error code?

Comment: it showed .Left = shp.Left

Comment: Am wondering if same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262403/powerpoint-vba-copy-shape-to-a-slide though I tried to introduce a long delay (30s) and still no luck