# VBA Select Image and copy to next slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to create a mini game in Powerpoint 2016. In the first slide there are 6 different pictures (heroes) and the user is asked to select a hero. How can I transfer their selection (picture) to the next slide in the presentation?

Comment: Got any code? Which part are you stuck on, specifically? Identifying the selection? Adding a shape/picture to the next slide? Positioning it? As it stands your question is rather vague, have you tried looking for a tutorial?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36262403/1188513) helps

Comment: I looked everywhere, found several codes but none of them does what I want to do. I tried to modify them, but I am rather new to VBA, so I am stuck. To explain better, in slide number one, I placed six shapes, each of them filled with a different picture. In the second slide, I have just one shape. On slide number one, the user is asked to select a picture (shape). I am looking for a code to record the user's selection and fill the shape in slide number two with the picture (shape fill) the user selected

Comment: So, yes, I am stuck on i) how to identify the selection and ii) how to transfer the selection to fill the shape on the next slide.

Comment: If you're doing this in slideshow view, the user can't select anything. However, you can assign a run-macro action setting to the picture shape.  If the macro starts out like Sub BlahBlan (oSh as Shape) the code can work with oSh as it will be a reference to the shape the user clicked.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up with this code. I know it is not the most elegant, so any enhancements/suggestions are more than welcome!

Sub fillShape(myShape As Shape)

```
Dim theAnswer As String
theAnswer = myShape.Name
Dim heroName As String
MsgBox "the name is " & theAnswer

If theAnswer = "Name1" Then
    ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(8).Fill.UserPicture ("C:\path\Name1.png")
ElseIf theAnwer = "Name2" Then
    ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(8).Fill.UserPicture ("C:\path\Name2.png")
ElseIf theAnwer = "Name3" Then
    ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(8).Fill.UserPicture ("C:\path\Name3.png")
Else
    MsgBox "something went wrong "
End If
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
```

End Sub